# EvoSuite java support for Java 7?

Tags: java, maven, version, evosuite

Which versions of Java are supported by `EvoSuite`?

I am running a maven build, following the instructions on the EvoSuite maven plugin page.

However, the build fails with the following message:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.evosuite.plugins:evosuite-maven-
plugin:0.1.1:generate (default-cli) on project simple: Execution default-cli of
 goal org.evosuite.plugins:evosuite-maven-plugin:0.1.1:generate failed: Unable 
to load the mojo 'generate' in the plugin 'org.evosuite.plugins:evosuite-maven-
plugin:0.1.1' due to an API incompatibility: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: 
org/evosuite/maven/GenerateMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Answer (score 0):

EvoSuite does support Java 7. The error message that you get seems like the Maven process you used is not using Java 7. You need to be sure that "mvn" is using the right Java version. Use `mvn -version` to check which one you are using.

See related post: [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class frontend.listener.StartupListener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028166/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-un?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I had to set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10 and this error is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

NO,at least JAVA8.You can go to the website of Evosuite to learn more.

Comment: Instead of writing "*you can go to the website of [something]*" add link to the exact point that supports your assumption

Comment: This directly contradicts the other answer. And perhaps support for java versions changed in the intervening years, providing proof (quoted text and links) would be much more helpful.